# How to use another profile in chat

Tags: support, chat, profile-page

I've a unique profile on "The Great Outdoors" (TGO) called ["OddDeer"](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/8060/odddeer). As I join the [chat of TGO](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2291/the-base-camp), I automatically do it with my SE network profile called ["OddDev"](https://stackexchange.com/users/3062937/odddev?tab=accounts).

[image: TGO chat]

How can I change my profile in chat to "OddDeer"?

Comment: This is odd....

Comment: @DeerHunter I somehow feel uncomfortable when you are around...

Comment: Of course, it will be super odd if @Deer will change the name to Dev Hunter on SO. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your [chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/177070/odddev), change the parent user to the one you want to show up:

> [image]

Comment: Worked for me perfectly :) Thanks!

Comment: Is the "[change]" option still there? I don't see it ([this is how it looks for me](https://imgur.com/a/LkRhtqS))

Comment: @HeyJude Stack Exchange has three chat domains: Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Exchange (this one), and [all the rest](https://chat.stackexchange.com/). Go to this link, go to your chat profile, and you should see this and be able to change your parent user. The other two (SO and MSE) have only one site in each, so nothing to change. :)